# Modify sequence execution order

Tags: java

I am using the chain of responsibility design pattern. My current code structure is as follows:

```
public abstract class Handle {
   private Handle next;
   
   public Handle linkTo(Handle next) {
      this.next = next;
      return next;
  
  public abstract boolean check(Object item) {}
  
  protected boolean checkNext(Object item) {
     if (next==null) {
        // all scenarios checked, no match
        return false;
     }
     return next.check(item); 
}
```

Is it now possible to change the defined chain of cases at runtime. By this I mean, say we have this chain at the start caseA --> caseB --> caseC. There is a match with caseB. Now I no longer wish to check against caseB as this case has been found thus changing the chain to caseA --> caseC. Is this possible with this design pattern?

Answer (score 1):

In order to remove a ring in the chain, I would do this:

```
public abstract class Case {
   private Case next;
   private Case previous; //<-- add a previous  
   
   public void linkTo(Case next) {
      this.next = next;
      this.next.previous = this; //<-- set the current instance as previous of the next instance
      //For example, if you are in an instance of CaseD, next is an instance of CaseE
      //You will be saying that the field .previous of instance E contains an instance of CaseD         
   }
  
  public abstract boolean checkCase(Message message) {}
  
  protected boolean checkNextCase(Message message) {
     if (next==null) {
        // all scenarios checked, no match
        return false;
     }
     return next.checkCase(message); 
}
```

Then, while in the concrete implementation (for example of `CaseB`), once you have a match you will just take the `this.previous` instance (if you're `CaseB`, it will be an instance of `CaseA`) and set it as `previous` of your own `next` (which is a `CaseC`):

```
public class caseB extends Case {
   public boolean checkCase(Message message) {
      boolean matched = //... your logic to match or not
      if (matched) {
          //Since you matched, you don't want B to be in the chain anymore. 
          this.next.previous = this.previous; //<-- set the previous of C to A, meaning you remove B, yourself, from the chain.  
      } 
      return matched;
   }
}
```

I will let you handle the corner cases (i.e. the first instance of the chain has no `previous` and the last instance of the chain has no `next`, hence be careful when you make the `.get()` on something that may have become `null` during a replacement).

---

Sample usage:

```
// Create cases
Case caseD = new CaseD(); //<-- last in the chain
Case caseC = new CaseC();
Case caseB = new CaseB();
Case caseA = new CaseA(); //<-- first in the chain

// Build chain 
caseA.linkTo(caseB); // <-- sets caseB as next for caseA, and caseA as previous for caseB
caseB.linkTo(caseC); // <-- sets caseC as next for caseB, and caseB as previous for caseC
caseC.linkTo(caseD) // <-- sets caseD as next for caseC, and caseC as previous for caseD

// Start chain 
List<Message> messages = // <-- your list of Messages to validate
messages.forEach(m -> {
    caseA.checkCase(m);
});
```

Suppose that in your list of 4 messages you have in this order `MessageC`, `MessageB`, `MessageA` and `MessageD`.

Starting chain: `caseA` -> `caseB` -> `caseC` -> `caseD`.

1. In the first iteration, the first `MessageC` will be matched by the third ring in the chain. Once matched, `this.next.previous` (`this.next` being `caseD`, so `this.next.previous` being `caseC` itself) will be set to `this.previous` which is `caseB`. Then the method will return without calling `checkNextCase()`.

Chain now: `caseA` -> `caseB` -> `caseD`.

2. The second iteration will pass a `MessageB`, which will be matched by the second ring in the chain. Once matched, `this.next.previous` (`this.next` being `caseD` again, so `this.next.previous` being `caseB` because you set it in the previous iteration) will be set to `this.previous` which is `caseA`. Then the method will return without calling `checkNextCase()`.

Chain now: `caseA` -> `caseD`.

3. The third iteration will pass a `MessageA`, which will be matched by the second ring in the chain. Once matched, `this.next.previous` (`this.next` being `caseD` again, so `this.next.previous` being `caseA` because you set it in the previous iteration) will be set to `this.previous`, which this time is `null`. Then the method will return without calling `checkNextCase()`.

Chain now: `caseD` only (no `previous`, no `next`).

4. In the fourth and last iteration, you will pass a `MessageD` that will be matched by the only `Case` left. Here be careful, because if you execute `this.next.previous` you will have a `NullPointerException` since `this.next` is `null`. In this case, you just `return true` and that's it.

Comment: Many thanks for your insight into this, its really helpful! I am a little confused as to how to handle the corner case of the first instance, caseA, being matched. Would I have to modify the 'performCheck' class to prevent the checkCase method from being called?

Comment: @Gecko29 I just mean be careful when accessing members that may be null. For example, if you are on the last ring of your chain, `this.next` will be `null` so if you call `this.next.previous` you will get a `NullPointerException`.  Same applies if you try to access a member of `this.previous` while in the first ring.The best is you prepare a unit test where you put some checkers in chain and then pass a set of `Message`s to that chain. You will figure out yourself where you'll have to add the `null`ity checks.

Comment: Ahh I see. I think I'm a little confused about the fact I start the chain by calling the checkCase method on the first case (caseA) and then from this the process of calling the case based on the value of 'next' begins.

Comment: @Gecko29 I have added an example. No, you don't need the checker class, you only need to create your chain and then call it over your list of Messages. See the example I've added.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Surely though, on every loop you are executing caseA.checkCase(m). Therefore the method containing the logic for the check of caseA will always be run even after case A has been matched and pointers updated?

Comment: @Gecko29 you should really create some unit tests and debug, you'd find out much easily than comments on SO how you should design your code to be 100% robust :)

Answer (score 0):

Add a flag called `enabled` and a relevant setter `setEnabled`. In your `checkCase` method add a check:

```
if (!enabled)
    return true;
```

P.S. You can refactor your checkForMatch method without a conditional.